# Rails i18n - Can't change the format of the errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

In my Rails app, I have the following translation

```
de:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        applicant:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Bitte nenne uns Deinen %{attribute}"
```

But when I check the errors on my models, I get the following message:

> Applicant name Bitte nenne uns Deinen Name

How come there is that "Applicant Name" at the beginning of the message?

And how can i remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must be using [**`full_messages`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_message) to show the errors. Something like this:

```
applicant.errors.full_messages
#=> ["Applicant name Bitte nenne uns Deinen Name"]
```

Change it to

```
applicant.errors.messages
#=> ["Bitte nenne uns Deinen Name"]
```

**NOTE:** [**`full_messages`**](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Errors.html#method-i-full_messages) will append attribute name before error message. That's why you are getting `Applicant name` appended to the message

**Solution2**

If you want to change `full_messages` then try changing

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{attribute} %{message}"
```

to

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

Comment: I take it you forgot `activerecord:` on your solution #2... but that does not change anything in the output. This is my code: https://hastebin.com/icamazepig.pl

Comment: My bad, you were right. Without `activerecord:` it works. Thanks!